# mapbox gl js coordinates update

Tags: angular, mapbox

i want to constantly update a point in my map, but the solutions i have racharched in advance do not cap. i want to edit an existing point using the id and set new coordians. i get the following error message when i try to run the following code :

"Property 'setData' does not exist on type 'AnySourceImpl'.
Property 'setData' does not exist on type 'RasterSource'.ts(2339)"

code :

```
this.map.getSource("me").setData({});
```

the code before where i created the point looks like this:

```
this.map.on('load', () => {
      const customMarkerImageUrl = './assets/Me.png';
      const image = new Image();
      image.onload = () => {
        this.map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
        this.map.addSource('point', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: [
              {
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                  type: 'point',
                  coordinates: [this.currentLong, this.currentLat] // replace lng and lat with the coordinates of the point.
                },
                properties: {
                  title: 'My Point',
                  id: 'me'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        });

        this.map.addLayer({
          id: 'me'
          type: 'symbol'
          source: 'point'
          layout: {
            'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
            'icon-size': 0.05 //5% of the original size of the image
          }
        });
      };

      image.src = customMarkerImageUrl;
    });
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: What is the result of `this.map.getSource("me")`?

Comment: the result is undefinied but why?